# How to send array of querystring with react and axios?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, axios, query-string

I am trying to use the query string with axios to filter some data from the backend, I can do it with the backend api but I was struggling when it came to the frontend with react on how to send the array of query string to the backend. Here is my backend endpoint with array of query string params, it is working fine when I tested with postman.

```
localhost:3040/v2/feedback/filter/average-ratings?receiver=62c2dd106742823a69f98dac&receiver=62aec70881e46a4794b3a424
```

[image]

Here is my frontend code that I tried to send the request but return the error

```
export const filterAverageRating = async (receiver) => {
  console.log('Receiver ID', receiver); //['62c2dd106742823a69f98dac', '62aec70881e46a4794b3a424']
  const accessJWT = sessionStorage.getItem('accessJWT');
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: accessJWT,
    },
  };
  const { data } = await axios.get(
    ENDPOINT_URL + 'filter/average-ratings',
    config,
    { params: { receiver } }
  );

  return data;
};
```

it return receiver is undefined from the backend, it means that there is something went wrong with query string in axios.

Comment: What is the endpoint coming in logs or network tab?

Comment: it said, `No content` status 204 and it seem not get the query string from the axios `http://localhost:3040/v2/feedback/filter/average-ratings` because it doesn't show the query string in the url endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paramsSerializer` for `axios`. This way your requested query param will keep appending its key e.g. `?query=one&query=two&query=three`

```
const { data } = await axios.get(ENDPOINT_URL + "filter/average-ratings", {
  ...config,
  params: receiver,
  paramsSerializer: (params) =>
    qs.stringify(params, { arrayFormat: "repeat" }),
});
```

> **Hint:** Your params are part of axios config while performing get requests.

Alternatively, if your API accepts comma separated queries as an array e.g. `query=one,two,three` you can simply use this without needing `paramsSerializer`

```
  ...
  params: receiver.join(","),
  ...
```

Comment: it shown this endpoint request in the backend and return `status 204 No content` because the endpoint with query string is not correct send from the frontend `/v2/feedback/filter/average-ratings?0=62aec70881e46a4794b3a424&1=62b73809c2ca370bcbb0715b`, it suppose to receive `/v2/feedback/filter/average-ratings?receiver=62aec70881e46a4794b3a424&receiver=62b73809c2ca370bcbb0715b` I still faced the problem... it was able to send array but with the wrong params name, receiver not 0 & 1

Comment: Oh, I just made a small change in the params from `params: receiver` to `params:{receiver: receiver}` and it worked fine. Thank you so much for your explanation, have a nice day :D